# Avoid the message 'Press space bar to continue" - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to Progress. I use the below query to call a external program from progress editor. The issue I am facing here is I'm getting the message **press space to continue** from the external program. Due to this message the program completion is not happening and it got stuck until I press any key from the keyboard. This **pause 0 before-hide no-message** helps to hide the message I think. Its not letting the program execution for the completion. let me know where am I making mistakes and modify the below query

```
output to value("/home/test/cim.out").
  input from value("/home/ast/cim.in").
  pause 0 before-hide no-message.
  {us/bbi/gprun.i ""xxxxx.p""}
  input close.
output close.
```

Comment: What does gprun.i look like? It's likely you need to change something there to get rid of the message.

Comment: @Jensd We cannot change the .i file as it is a standard one

Comment: @Jensd is it possible to add some key functionality ..if yes the can you help to modify

Comment: I havent worked with mfg/pro so maybe someone else can help. Unless it's actually in the "xxx.p"-program the message comes from.

Comment: @Jensd I think you can help me. This message appears to the main screen and expecting user to give any inputs. So in this case is it possible to add auto inputs by program itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pause 0 before-hide.
```

Will override default PAUSE messages that occur when a pause is being automatically generated. For instance when a FRAME is being automatically hidden or a series of MESSAGE statements are being generated. It does not, however, override an explicit PAUSE statement. For instance:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

pause 0 before-hide.

do i = 1 to 10:
  message i.
  if i modulo 5 = 0 then pause message "i modulo 5 = 0".
end.
```

To solve that problem you will need to edit "xxxxx.p" and find out where the PAUSE is coming from.

Comment: I found it and fixed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `QUIT.` at the end of the procedure to ensure it's full closing. I was having the same issue a while ago...